# Why am I getting an index out of range exception

Tags: c#, indexoutofrangeexception

I don't understand why I'm getting an index out of range exception when I call any of the move functions.
I have the player set in the lower right corner of the "map" so it should be able to move north or west but I keep getting an index out of range exception for some reason.

This is the main program:

```
namespace DungeonWalk
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int length, width;
        Console.WriteLine("What size dungeon do you want to traverse?");
        try
        {
            Console.Write("Length: ");
            length = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Width: ");
            width = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid parameters.");
            return;
        }
        var map = Tile.CreateMap(length, width);
        var player = new Player(map.GetLength(0) - 1, map.GetLength(1) - 1);
        while(true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What do you want to move next?");
            var move = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            while (true)
            {
                switch (move)
                {
                    case "north":
                        Move.North(player, map[player.YPosition, player.XPosition]);
                        break;
                    case "south":
                        Move.South(player, map[player.YPosition, player.XPosition]);
                        break;
                    case "east":
                        Move.East(player, map[player.YPosition, player.XPosition]);
                        break;
                    case "west":
                        Move.West(player, map[player.YPosition, player.XPosition]);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Not a vaild direction. Use cardinal directions.");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is the code to move:

```
namespace DungeonWalk
{
class Move
{
    public static void North(Player player, Tile tile)
    {
        if(tile.NorthWall)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There is a wall before you. You cannot proceed any further.");
        }
        else
        {
            player.YPosition -= 1;
        }
    }

    public static void South(Player player, Tile tile)
    {
        if (tile.SouthWall)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There is a wall before you. You cannot proceed any further.");
        }
        else
        {
            player.YPosition += 1;
        }
    }

    public static void West(Player player, Tile tile)
    {
        if (tile.WestWall)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There is a wall before you. You cannot proceed any further.");
        }
        else
        {
            player.XPosition -= 1;
        }
    }

    public static void East(Player player, Tile tile)
    {
        if (tile.EastWall)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There is a wall before you. You cannot proceed any further.");
        }
        else
        {
            player.XPosition += 1;
        }
    }
}
}
```

And finally here is the code for the CreateMap

```
public static Tile[,] CreateMap(int length, int width)
    {
        var map = new Tile[length, width];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                map[i, j] = new Tile(j, i, length, width);
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
```

Comment: Exactly what line is throwing this exception?

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: I am certain there is a very good chance that if Michael would look at the stack trace first before posting it here, he would be able to quickly rectify the problem by himself

Comment: From what I can see the problem lies in `Tile.CreateMap`, but you haven't shown us that code so I can't say for sure. The trick to asking good questions on Stack Overflow is to provide enough code for someone to reproduce your issue. You haven't done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two `while` loops in the main program look slightly strange, and I am not sure if it is intentional.

The current implementation:

```
while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("What do you want to move next?");
    var move = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    while (true)
    {
        switch (move)
        {
            // Move player...
        }
    }
}
```

only asks the user for a move once, then the inner `while` loop keeps moving the player in the specified direction forever. (Note that the `break` will only break out of the `switch` statement, not out of the inner `while`).

If you eliminate the inner loop you gain the ability to perform one step at a time:

```
while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("What do you want to move next?");
    var move = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

    switch (move)
    {
        // Move player...
    }
}
```

Unless there is something funky going on in the `Tile` accessors (e.g. `NorthWall` or `XPosition`), I don't see anything in the `Move` methods that could cause an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

The `map` indexing could be getting out of bounds though, e.g. this line:

```
map[player.YPosition, player.XPosition]
```

If the walls are not configured correctly, then, as described above, the inner `while` loop will keep the player forever moving in the same direction until the array index increases beyond the bounds of the map, generating an exception.

Comment: Wow... I completely missed the fact that I had accidentally put two while loops in. I feel really dumb. Thanks a lot.